# How to wait for a WebElement to have a specific text value (Selenium C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I know I can wait for an element to *exist* by doing this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var element = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("foo-status")));
```

If it doesn't exist within 5 seconds, `element` is null.

How do I get Selenium to wait for the element to have a certain text value?

(I have answered my own question, but would be keen for any better answers or improvements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier solution for your usecase to wait for the element to have a certain text can be implemented with the help of [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) in-conjunction with the method [**TextToBePresentInElement**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_TextToBePresentInElement.htm) as follows :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var expectedText = "good";
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(By.Id("foo-status"), expectedText));
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a filter method that returns null if the text does not match.

```
public static IWebElement ElementTextFilter(IWebElement webElement, string text) {
    if (webElement == null)
        return null;

    return webElement.Text.Equals(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? webElement : null;
}

// ...

var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var expectedText = "good";
var element = wait.Until(d =>
    ElementTextFilter(d.FindElement(By.Id("foo-status")), expectedText)
);
```

Can easily turn this into an extension method which is a bit cleaner.

```
public static class WebElementExtensions {
    public static IWebElement WithText(this IWebElement webElement, string text) {
        if (webElement == null)
            return null;

        return webElement.Text.Equals(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            ? webElement : null;
    }

// ...

var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var expectedText = "good";
var element = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("foo-status")).WithText(expectedText));
```